# cant make an object I added to a knockout model observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is the fiddle demonstrating the problem http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/31955/

I made a representation of my actual problem in the fiddle.  I am loading an object via web api 2 and ajax and inserting it into my knockout model. however when I do this it appears the attributes are no longer observable. I'm not sure how to make them observable.  in the example you will see that the text box and span load with the original value however updating the textbox does not update the value.

here is the javascript.

```
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.emp = ko.observable('');
  this.loademp = function() {
    self.emp({
      name: 'Bryan'
    });

  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {

  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

here is the html

```
<button data-bind="click: loademp">
  load emp
</button>
<div data-bind="with: emp">
  <input data-bind="value: name" />
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `name` property observable:

```
this.loademp = function(){
 self.emp({name: ko.observable('Bryan')});
}
```

Comment: yeah that is what I am trying to avoid if at all possible because the object coming back is pretty large.  so I would prefer on success of the ajax call to have self.emp(result) as opposed to having to manipulate result

Comment: well, binding `value` here `data-bind="value: name"` expects observable, and if's not, I don't knockout can update it's values because other components can't subscribe to not observable values. you'll probably have to go through object properties and make them all observable

Comment: actually you gave me an idea. I can get the result from the ajax call then loop through the key value pair of everything in the json object and turn each one into an observable. I think that would work right?

Comment: yeah that worked pretty well I marked your answer as correct. I looped through the json object and got the key value pairs. here is the fiddle.   http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/31958/